# MySQL Column headers into a single column, second column for the values

Tags: mysql, sql, cursors

I currently have a table that shows the data I need in the format of

`SELECT * FROM XYZ;`

```
Date | Brand | Game1| Game2 | Game3  |  
2017 | xxxxx  | xxxxxx  | ---------- | -----------|

2017 | xxxxx  | ----------| yyyyyyy | -----------|

2017 | xxxxx  | ----------| -----------| yyyyyyy |
```

The way I would like the data presented is with 4 columns in total, like this:

```
Date | Brand | GameName | Value

2017 | xxxxx | Game1 | 1234567.89

2017 | xxxxx | Game2 | 98.7654321

2017 | xxxxx | Game3 | 12345987.65
```

The reason for doing this is so that the data becomes easier to filter through to find specific values.

I've tried most other suggestions on SO but haven't had much success yet

(Such as `group_concat`).

One suggestion that did work was doing Union all, however I need a dynamic query 
as the table will continue to be added to in the future.

Currently I'm trying to set up a cursor to do it.

Comment: What are all those dashes?  Are they really dashes or is something else there, e.g. empty string or null?

Comment: In the table they are just 0's

Comment: In this question someone asked a similar question. The keyword here is `transponding` or `unpivot`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238717/unpivot-dynamic-columns-to-rows-missing-data-from-last-columns

Answer (score 2):

If your table will keep having new columns then whichever query you use, you will have to first get all the columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE`, here's an approach:

- Get all the column names with `%Game%` pattern
- Use `UNION` or any other query to get the output

Below is an example:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='db_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Game%';
```

Now, from the output of this query, construct a dynamic `UNION` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT Date, Brand, `<column>`, Value
FROM table

UNION

SELECT Date, Brand, `<column>`, Value
FROM table
```

Comment: How can I get `<column>` into my final table if there is nothing to join it on to?

Comment: You would iterate the result set of the first query and create union queries for the final result. `<column>` is just the value of a row from the first query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an unpivot combined with an aggregation to generate the output you want.  Appreciate that the value you want to compute for each game coincides with the sum of the respective game column.  This is so because you said that all other values are zero.

```
SELECT
    Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Game1 <> 0 THEN Brand END) AS Brand,
    'Game1' AS GameName,
    SUM(Game1) AS Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Date, MAX(CASE WHEN Game2 <> 0 THEN Brand END), 'Game2', SUM(Game2)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Date, MAX(CASE WHEN Game3 <> 0 THEN Brand END), 'Game3', SUM(Game3)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select Date, Brand, 'Game1', Game1 where Game1 is not null
UNION ALL
select Date, Brand, 'Game2' Game2 where Game2 is not null
UNION ALL
select Date, Brand, 'Game3' Game3 where Game3 is not null
```

you can save this as a view and query it directly for your results

Comment: MySQL does not support CTE, but in any case your data does not match the data in the question, q.v. the above comments.

Comment: in that case I will remove the cte and restructure the data

Comment: That would work but the issue is that I need a dynamic query