# select the 5 columns with highest values using php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, union

I need 5  columns with highest values (values must be sum of each column) for report. I have about 40 contury colunms something like england_turist, polad_turists, us_turists, india_turists... eng - 152(sum), pol - 280(sum), us - 54(sum), in - 36(sum)... and query needs to pick pol - 280 and eng - 152. So query need to sum every column and pick 5 columns with highest values.

I got result from here but how to create query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT 'Bmw' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(bmw) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
     UNION
     SELECT 'Mercedes' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(mercedes) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
     UNION
     SELECT 'Opel' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(opel) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
     UNION
     SELECT 'Nissan' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(nissan) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
     UNION
     SELECT 'Peguoet' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(peguoet) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
     UNION
     SELECT 'Volkswagen' AS vrstaautomobila, SUM(volkswagen) AS brautomobila FROM unos_korisnika
)
AS results
ORDER BY brautomobila DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Holy cow you made a column for each country? Why not make a tourist column and a country column? This is not how SQL is meant to be.

Comment: It would be even easier to make your query, using group by, order by, top(5), etc

Comment: @PhiterFernandes You are right but do not use this type of language at here

Comment: let me show you... i have a Hotel name... every hotel put record of turists income every day of each contury, so need to be columns. so i need now which contury have best income and later i will need top 5 hotels. http://prntscr.com/cwm1ah

Comment: @PhiterFernandes has a point, but I know things are as they are, not always our choice. In your case I would take a look in this question, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows

Comment: @Sandi Budic: You are wrong. The datamodel is very bad. You think you could not insert the daily data in your table if you had a record per country rather than a column per country? No. The only difference would be that you would insert several records instead of only one. No big deal.

Comment: I know it sucks when people give you a table with an ugly layout, maybe you can make your voice be heard and suggest them to change this structure. Tell them that it's better and will make it faster.

Comment: hm can you show me hotel name and some information about hotel and 5 contury work  as row... and inserting about 40 different values for this row every day...

Answer (score 1):

Transpose the table (convert columns to rows) and then select the top values.

```
select * from transposed_table order by value_column desc limit 5
```

you may use [How to transpose mysql table rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns) to transpose your data or may be this [SQL - How to transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose)

Comment: let me show you... i have a Hotel name... every hotel put record of turists income every day of each contury, so need to be columns. so i need now which contury have best income and later i will need top 5 hotels. http://prntscr.com/cwm1ah

Comment: is posible to do somethig like `SELECT  SUM(at_turista) as a, SUM(bg_turista) as b, SUM(ba_turista) as c, SUM(gr_turista) as d, SUM(dk_turista) as e, SUM(is_turista) as f, SUM(it_turista) as g
FROM mytable` and get higher values from a,b,c,d,f,g.

Comment: at_turista what is this?

Comment: SELECT SUM(at_turista) as a, SUM(bg_turista) as b, SUM(ba_turista) as c, SUM(gr_turista) as d, SUM(dk_turista) as e, SUM(is_turista) as f, SUM(it_turista) as g FROM mytable desc limit 5

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy at_turista is column name of turists from Austria.

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy sql code work in sql... but i dont know how to make query code in php