# Translate select columns in a row to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

i've spent a few hours tinkering with this problem to no avail. I have a dataset with rows that i'd like to subselect specific columns of into a different dataset.

The issue i'm having is translating the `AT`,`BB`,`BO`,`ES`,`LK` into a single `partner` column while grouped by FID and time.

I have been able to reproduce most of this dataset on my own. The `AT`... columns are provided initially as a 0, 1, 5 or  10. The only data I am curious about is 1s and 5s, and cast as the column name. The inital dataset is produced by this query:

```
select FID, `time`, 
if((`AT` != 0 and `AT` < 10), "AT", "") as `AT`,
if((`BB` != 0 and `BB` < 10), "BB", "") as `BB`,
if((`BO` != 0 and `BO` < 10), "BO", "") as `BO`,
if((`BT` != 0 and `BT` < 10), "BT", "") as `BT`,
if((`ES` != 0 and `ES` < 10), "ES", "") as `ES`
from f_data group by FID, `time`;
```

## Example Input

```
`FID`  `time` `AT``BB``BO``ES``LK`
BT201   7:00   AT  BB      ES  LK  
BT201   7:15   AT  BB  BO      LK  
BT201   7:30           BO  ES  LK  
BT201   7:45   AT  BB  BO  ES  LK  
BT201   8:00   AT      BO  ES  LK
```

## Desired Output

```
`FID`  `time` `partner`
BT201   7:00   AT
BT201   7:00   BB
BT201   7:00   ES
BT201   7:00   LK
BT201   7:15   AT
BT201   7:15   BB
BT201   7:15   BO
BT201   7:15   LK
```

I've been able to produce this output via R using plyr but haven't been able to produce this output in pure MySQL. If required the `mysql --version` output is as follows:

`Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.58, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: Hi @Ibu, unfortunately this data is provided in a view that I cannot view or modify the structure of.

Comment: In order to use mysql, you need to be able to write a query.

Comment: @Ibu I'll format the query i've reproduced the dataset in the initial question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing Dynamic Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows)

Comment: I was able to complete this using the information found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table  

This can likely be marked as duplicate due to that answer.

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FID, `time`, `AT` as `partner`
from input_table
where `AT` = "AT"

union all

select FID, `time`, `BB` as `partner`
from input_table
where `BB` = "BB"

union all

select FID, `time`, `BO` as `partner`
from input_table
where `BO` = "BO"

union all

select FID, `time`, `ES` as `partner`
from input_table
where `ES` = "ES"

union all

select FID, `time`, `LK` as `partner`
from input_table
where `LK` = "LK"

order by FID, `time`, `partner`
```