# Find the Number of columns with the same value

Tags: php, mysql

```
+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Uid | Q1 |  Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 | Q7 |
+=====+=====+====+====+====+====+====+====+
|  1  |  1  |  0 |  1 |  0 | 1  |  1 |  0 |
+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

This is a structure of my database. I want to fetch number of columns where `uid = $_SESSION['Uid']`.
I want Numbers of columns where 0 is present in between `Q1, Q2, Q5, Q7`
something like this, (not a query its just for reference)

```
$Uid = $_SESSION['Uid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Q1, Q2, Q5, Q7 FROM userdata WHERE Uid = '$Uid' && have 0");
echo mysql_num_fields($result);
```

so it will return 2
or this can be solve by using count function.
Or how should I transform or create a new table like this after selecting all fields for that particular user?

```
+----+----+
|  Q |  A |
+====+====+
| Q1 |  1 |
+====+====+
| Q2 |  0 |
+====+====+
| Q3 |  1 |
+====+====+
| Q4 |  0 |
+====+====+
| Q5 |  1 |
+====+====+
| Q6 |  1 |
+====+====+
| Q7 |  0 |
+====+====+
```

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Fix your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: `SELECT 4 - Q1 - Q2 - Q5 - Q7 FROM userdata WHERE Uid = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the results of `IF` :

```
SELECT IF(Q1=0,1,0) + IF(Q2=0,1,0) + IF(Q5=0,1,0) + IF(Q7=0,1,0) as total
FROM userdata WHERE Uid = '$Uid';
```

Outputs:

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     2 |
+-------+
```

Comment: it does not work either. It gives me 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @Ameya I've tested with the record in your question and give me 2. On which data have you made this test please ?

Comment: @Ameya This query counts the number of columns in Q1,Q2,Q5 and Q7 that having a zero value.

Comment: @Ameya Did you find a way in PHP to get the results?

Comment: yeah, it did work thanks and what if I want Q with 1 value?
should I invert this like, `IF(Q1=1,0,1)`?

Comment: @Ameya `IF (column=value_you_want, 1, 0)`, to count the columns with the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that each field = 0

```
SELECT Q1, Q2, Q5, Q7 
FROM userdata WHERE Uid = '$Uid' AND (Q1=0 OR Q2=0 OR Q5=0 OR Q7=0)
```

Comment: I used this command previously but it gives me result 4 which is the total number of fields I am selecting regardless it contains 0 no not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT` operator to invert a true/false value (which is represented in MySQL as 1/0), so:

```
SELECT (NOT q1) + (NOT q2) + (NOT q5) + (NOT q7) AS total
FROM userdata
WHERE Uid = $Uid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cac781/2)

If you prefer to think of them as numbers rather than truth values, you could use `(1 - q1)`, etc.

Comment: That's give the same results of my anwser, but more readable :)

Comment: @Syscall I know, just another way to write it. Also `(1 - q1)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can UNPIVOT your table and query it as well.

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows) describes unpivoting in mysql. this is especially usefull if your table columns are dynamic and/or if you need to generate complex reports.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.