# Mysql pivot table opposite

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with data like this:

```
a | b | c | d | e
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

and I want it to be:

```
name | value
 a   |   1
 b   |   2
 c   |   3
 d   |   4
 e   |   5
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: you can use union all, but this is not dynamic.

Comment: I am trying to avoid union all because then I have to run a  query for each name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing Dynamic Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows)

Comment: I think that yes